# Trouble with PyQt4 List Widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

My problem is the following:
I have a program that I created in QT Designer and added some code in Python.
There is an main window and two windows which appear when you click a button in the window before.
The List Widget is in the second window:

Hope with this picture you can understand what I mean

[image]

So now I want to add some Items to my list widget.

```
    def add_number_to_list(self):
        self.ui.list_of_numbers.addItem('test')
```

So I call this function on another place but nothing happened.
If I add an print command, to test if the function works: The print is shown. But nothing appears in the list widget...

What is wrong?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import p_design, p_edit_numbers, p_add_number

number_to_add = ''

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = p_design.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        self.ui.manually_alarm.clicked.connect(self.alarm)
        self.ui.edit_numbers.clicked.connect(self.open_edit_numbers)

    def alarm(t1,t2):
        #send sms to numbers
        print('ALARM!')

    def open_edit_numbers(self):
        self.test = EditNumbers(self)
        self.test.show()

class EditNumbers(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = p_edit_numbers.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.add_number.clicked.connect(self.open_add_number)

            ### Problem! ###
    def add_number_to_list(self):
        self.ui.list_of_numbers.addItems('test')
            ################

    def open_add_number(self):
            self.t3 = AddNumber(self)
            self.t3.show()

class AddNumber(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = p_add_number.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.add.clicked.connect(self.add_number)

    def add_number(self):
        global number_to_add
        editnumbers=EditNumbers()
        editnumbers.add_number_to_list()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    

main()
```

Comment: With 2 lines you cannot expect that much, anyway the most probable cause (I think) is UI is not repainting for some reason. Maybe the main event loop is not running.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. There is nothing in the example code that calls `add_number_to_list` and there are no signals connected to it.

Comment: I added some thing to the question and hope it is more clear now!